# Java Slick2D rotating Shapes

Tags: java, slick

I'm having a problem with rotating a Shape in Slick2D for Java

I have a code in screen render which works properly:

```
Shape box = new Rectangle(100,100,32,32);
    box = box.transform( Transform.createRotateTransform(1f,116,116));
    gfx.draw(box);
```

```
public Entity(int x,int y,int sheet,Shape collisionbox1){
    sheetIndex = sheet;
    sheetX=0;
    sheetY=0;
    rotation =0f;
    position = new Vector2f(x,y);
    this.collisionBox = collisionbox1;
} // entity inallization

map1.entity_list.add(new Entity(100, 100 , 0,new Rectangle(100,100,32,32))); // thats where i add entity into my map

public void render(GameContainer game, StateBasedGame state, Graphics gfx)
{    Image img =Start.theContent.SheetsList.get(sheetIndex).getSprite(sheetX, sheetY);
    img.setRotation(rotation);
    img.draw(position.x-Start.theGame.camera.x, position.y-Start.theGame.camera.y);
    gfx.draw(this.getBounds());
} // thats where i render entity (camera.x = 0 camera.y =0)

public boolean update(GameContainer game,StateBasedGame state,int delta) {
    rotation +=1f;
    if(rotation >360)rotation -=360;
    if(rotation < 0)rotation += 360;
    collisionBox = collisionBox.transform(Transform.createRotateTransform(1f,116,116));
    return true;
} // here is where i routate the entity collisionBox = Rect{100,100,32,32} so center should be 116 116
```

When I start the program I get random moving & rotating rectangle on the screen.

When I check its x,y,and center it writes 0,0 and a random center. For example:

```
0,0 116.000046,115.99997
0,0 0.0 0.0 116.00006 116.00001
```

Its really strange to me. Sorry for the bad explanation; if you need to know anything else about my code, please tell me.

Comment: You have forever to write these questions. Take the time to use some capitalisation and actually write out your you's and so on. It's better for the people reading it, which means you'll probably get more attention.

Comment: Is rotation based on degrees or radians?